# Why is the rating always showing the max amount of rating, when hidden fields dictate otherwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to be clever with JS and jQuery, and using a 3PP called 'Raty', which simply puts stars into a div, useful when you want to show what rating an item has been given.

Now, here is the javascript I use to dynamically assign values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
    var starting = parseInt($('#toplistRating'+i+'val').val());
    $('#toplistRating'+i).raty({
        number: 3,
        half: true,
        readOnly: true,
        start: starting,
        hintList: ['could be improved', 'alright', 'AWESOME']
    });
}

});
```

And there is a list of items I get from the DB. Here are all 5 (note they are essentially the same, bar some ids being different by 1):

```
 <div id="toplist" class="std-column">

        <p class="toplist-links">switch to top: <a href="index?toplistSelected=1">1</a> | <a href="index?toplistSelected=2">2</a>
            <a href="index?toplistSelected=3">3</a> | <a href="index?toplistSelected=4">4</a></p>

            <div class="toplist-item">
                <a href="viewpic?id=35">
                <p class="toplist-num">1.</p>
                    <img src="image?id=35&amp;thumbnail=1" class="toplist-pic">
                    <div class="toplist-info">
                        <div id="toplistRating1" style="cursor: default;" title="AWESOME"><img class="toplistRating1" title="AWESOME" alt="1" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating1-1">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating1" title="AWESOME" alt="2" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating1-2">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating1" title="AWESOME" alt="3" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating1-3"><input type="hidden" id="toplistRating1-score" name="score" value="3"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="6" id="toplistRating1val">
                        <p class="toplist-text"><span class="soft">1 ratings</span></p>
                    </div>
               </a> 
            </div>   

            <div class="toplist-item">
                <a href="viewpic?id=7">
                <p class="toplist-num">2.</p>
                    <img src="image?id=7&amp;thumbnail=1" class="toplist-pic">
                    <div class="toplist-info">
                        <div id="toplistRating2" style="cursor: default;" title="AWESOME"><img class="toplistRating2" title="AWESOME" alt="1" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating2-1">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating2" title="AWESOME" alt="2" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating2-2">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating2" title="AWESOME" alt="3" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating2-3"><input type="hidden" id="toplistRating2-score" name="score" value="3"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="5" id="toplistRating2val">
                        <p class="toplist-text"><span class="soft">3 ratings</span></p>
                    </div>
               </a> 
            </div>   

            <div class="toplist-item">
                <a href="viewpic?id=11">
                <p class="toplist-num">3.</p>
                    <img src="image?id=11&amp;thumbnail=1" class="toplist-pic">
                    <div class="toplist-info">
                        <div id="toplistRating3" style="cursor: default;" title="AWESOME"><img class="toplistRating3" title="AWESOME" alt="1" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating3-1">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating3" title="AWESOME" alt="2" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating3-2">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating3" title="AWESOME" alt="3" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating3-3"><input type="hidden" id="toplistRating3-score" name="score" value="3"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="5" id="toplistRating3val">
                        <p class="toplist-text"><span class="soft">5 ratings</span></p>
                    </div>
               </a> 
            </div>   

            <div class="toplist-item">
                <a href="viewpic?id=8">
                <p class="toplist-num">4.</p>
                    <img src="image?id=8&amp;thumbnail=1" class="toplist-pic">
                    <div class="toplist-info">
                        <div id="toplistRating4" style="cursor: default;" title="AWESOME"><img class="toplistRating4" title="AWESOME" alt="1" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating4-1">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating4" title="AWESOME" alt="2" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating4-2">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating4" title="AWESOME" alt="3" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating4-3"><input type="hidden" id="toplistRating4-score" name="score" value="3"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="4" id="toplistRating4val">
                        <p class="toplist-text"><span class="soft">5 ratings</span></p>
                    </div>
               </a> 
            </div>   

            <div class="toplist-item">
                <a href="viewpic?id=12">
                <p class="toplist-num">5.</p>
                    <img src="image?id=12&amp;thumbnail=1" class="toplist-pic">
                    <div class="toplist-info">
                        <div id="toplistRating5" style="cursor: default;" title="AWESOME"><img class="toplistRating5" title="AWESOME" alt="1" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating5-1">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating5" title="AWESOME" alt="2" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating5-2">&nbsp;<img class="toplistRating5" title="AWESOME" alt="3" src="images/star-on.png" id="toplistRating5-3"><input type="hidden" id="toplistRating5-score" name="score" value="3"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="4" id="toplistRating5val">
                        <p class="toplist-text"><span class="soft">5 ratings</span></p>
                    </div>
               </a> 
            </div>   

    </div>
```

Raty  - http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/ - only shows 3 Stars (out of 3) for every item, when I know that the scores are lower, like 2 stars for the last 2.

Please help me. I suspect my problem lies with suspect use of javascript, especially that for-loop. If you need more info just let me know and I'll modify the question.

Comment: Have you checked which value starting has for each item?  If this is always 3 then that could be your issue.

Comment: **What is the REAL problem here?** **A** Invalid rating display (as I understand from the question) or **B** jQuery selector not working (as I understand the question title)? If it's the first one then you should change the title of your question.

Comment: @Robert, there was no html last time I looked!  Looks like that is his issue. Will always be 3 of it's between 4-6.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, the problem is the incorrect rating display. Its my additional concern that I am doing something silly with jQuery/JS and that is why its not working. In other words I'm not sure which it is!

Comment: @nasty: Then you should change question title, because it's misleading readers that something's not working with jQuery.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, you are quite right. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: `p` and `div` tags (and even `input`) inside `a`? What is this nonsense?!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal perhaps you'd be so kind as to explain why it is nonsense. It works. It's all a BIG link. Can you suggest some sort of best practice or what you'd do to improve this?

Comment: @nasty: I thought that it was invalid HTML, but actually I'm not so sure now. Looks like it might be valid HTML 5, but _invalid_ HTML 4.01 (strict). Anyway, using "it works [for me, on my browser, today]" as proof that you're doing it properly is not sufficient general. :)

Comment: OK, yea, HTML 4 won't let you put the block-level `p` inside inline-level `a`. It may happen to work for you, but you cannot guarantee that it'll work for everybody and you should avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of starting comes from the hidden input field in the div.  From the sample html, these values are all greater than 3.

6, 5, 5, 4 for the four items mentioned.

These will max out at 3 since that is the star range.

Change the values of the hidden input fields to <=3 and you should see different star images.

If you want to include half stars, then try parseFloat rather than parseInt then / 2.0 afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for that, that is exactly what I forgot to do!